# Need to generate world map matrix along with different coloured region and marker on locations

Tags: ios, swift, world-map

Need to draw a custom world map drawing either the complete world map or a certain region. Also highlighting different regions with different colours.

I have tried https://github.com/KiloKilo/WorldMatrix. I am able to colour the regions but unable to draw custom regions and provide custom colour to certain regions. Unable to find any other library.

Using below code, it shows nothing

```
let generator = WorldMatrixGenerator()
// Set the number of columns per rows (Default: 100)
generator.columns = 20
// Set your desired map cutting (Default: .world)
// use .custom(north, east, south, west) for a custom bounding
generator.mapCutting = .europe
// Set the output type (.enum, .ascii, .emoji) (Default: .enum)
generator.exportType = .enum
// Generates the world array
generator.generate()
```

Basically want to achieve the one in the image. Can someone let me know how can draw custom regions?

Thanks for the help in advance.[image]